# not show take(4) Data in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

i Creating News Site in ASP.Net MVC .

I Want to Show 4 last Row Data in Database When Them Type Is ("SP") .

But When i Run Project Show Me Just Last Row .

How I Resolve it ?

My Database : [Database Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ2d0.png)

I Create Repository This .

```
public List<Tbl_News> GetSpecialNews()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Tbl_News> qGetSpecialNews = (from a in db.Tbl_News
                                   where a.Type.Equals("sp")
                                   select a).OrderByDescending(s => s.ID).Skip(0).Take(4).ToList();
            return qGetSpecialNews;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Partial View :

```
@{
            foreach (var item in RNews.GetSpecialNews())
            {
                <div class="sec-special-page-news-img">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/NewsPic/@item.Image" />
                </div>
                <div class="sec-special-page-news-body">
                    <a href="@item.ID">@item.Title</a>
                    <ul class="mini-info">
                        <li>@item.Date<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
        }
```

Home Controll :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Rep_News RNews = new Rep_News();
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var q = RNews.GetSpecialNews();
        return View(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I got to ask... Do you always write in Pascal Case?

Comment: No need to skip is you are not skipping any records. Just do `.Skip(4)` and that should be enough. If you are only getting 1 record then there is only one record that matches your filter.

Comment: no . its not work . i put the pic of database

Comment: How many records you have in that table with Type="sp" ?

Comment: 4 record in my data base

Comment: Your code should return 4 records. Also, you do not need to call `RNews.GetSpecialNews()` method again in your view as your are doing that in your action method and passing it to the view. Just do a foreach on the Model.

Comment: try to filter a.Type.Contains("sp"), maybe you have some space beside sp

Comment: `Contains` its not work .

Comment: `Your code should return 4 records. Also, you do not need to call RNews.GetSpecialNews() method again in your view as your are doing that in your action method and passing it to the view. Just do a foreach on the Model.`   How Do This ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from comments

> Your code should return 4 records. Also, you do not need to call
>   RNews.GetSpecialNews() method again in your view as your are doing
>   that in your action method and passing it to the view. Just do a
>   foreach on the Model

```
public List<Tbl_News> GetSpecialNews() {
    try {
        List<Tbl_News> qGetSpecialNews = 
            (from a in db.Tbl_News
             where a.Type.Equals("sp")
             select a)
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.ID)
            .Take(4)
            .ToList();
        return qGetSpecialNews;
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

View

```
@model List<Tbl_News>
@{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="sec-special-page-news-img">
            <img src="~/Content/img/NewsPic/@item.Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="sec-special-page-news-body">
            <a href="@item.ID">@item.Title</a>
            <ul class="mini-info">
                <li>@item.Date<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
}
```